# Checking a date is between two dates

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

In ColdFusion I can see the code below, however it does not seem to work. I want to make sure discount is only applied if the valid from and to dates are in range, see below.

```
if (
  DATEDIFF("d", discount.ValidFrom(), now()) >= 0 
  AND  
  DATEDIFF("d", now(), discount.ValidTo()) <= 0
){
   // ALL OK Accept Discount
}
    else 
{
   // Discount is no Longer Valid boo!
}
```

Comment: Rather than rolling your own, how about trying this one from CFLib: [IsDateBetween](http://cflib.org/udf/IsDateBetween)?

Comment: CF 2016 errors trying to interpret `isDateBetween` as a variable??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic is a bit off. Right now you're returning

```
if ({positive_number} and {negative_number})
```

which returns false. You should be checking if dateDiff("d", today, discount.to()) is also >= 0.

```
<cfscript>
    local = {};
    local.start = createDate( 2011, 10, 01 );
    local.end = createDate( 2011, 10, 30 );
    local.today = now();
    local.valid = false;

    if ( (dateDiff("d", local.start, local.today) >= 0) 
            AND (dateDiff("d", local.today, local.end) >= 0) ){
        local.valid = true;
    }
</cfscript>

<cfoutput>
x < z: #dateDiff("d", local.start, local.today) GTE 0#
<hr />
z < y: #dateDiff("d", local.today, local.end) GTE 0#
<hr />
Valid: #local.valid#
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: anything I need to know about the two solutions posted is there any difference? Peter Boughton solution without data dif would this be an issue?

Comment: They'll both work. I find mine more understandable - when I see it I instantly know it's a comparison and checking that a date is within a range. With a DateDiff solution I have to see that both items are days and process the ordering and the >= or <= part, which is a lot more effort when quickly scanning code. The computer itself wont care though; they'll both achieve the same effect.

Comment: Thank you for your help and explaining it.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
Today = Int(Now());

if ( Today GTE Int(discount.ValidFrom())
 AND Today LTE Int(discount.ValidTo())
   )
{
    // discount is valid
}
else
{
    // no longer valid
}
```

It works because datetimes are basically just numbers - with the integer/whole part being the days and the decimal/fraction part being the time.

So applying the [`Int`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Int) function will convert a datetime to a whole day date, and then you can just do a simple numeric comparison to ensure it is within the ranges.

I find this far more readable and understandable than the [`DateDiff`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/DateDiff) stuff - there's no confusion over the ordering of things, which I think is the problem with your provided code snippet (you've switched both order and lte/gte; you only wanted to change one or the other).

Comment: Just to note that in CFML there's no Floor() function, use Int() instead.

Comment: Heh, yeah; I always do that. :/ [Int](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Int) or [Fix](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Fix) will both work for this. (The functions differ only in how negative numbers are treated, which only comes into play for dates before 1900, and thus unlikely to be a factor for voucher dates.)

Comment: Lovely explanation! I'm sure this is explained in CF documentation somewhere, but I've been CF'ing awhile and am very happy to have learned a new way to handle coding of date comparison.